# Azure ACI Private IP Changes When Re-Deployed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-container-instances

When I re-deploy my container group, the private IP address changes.  It's usually one of three addresses.  So, I recognize that my load balancer can just have all three of those, and seems to know which one is actually live at the moment, but I would much rather be able to have the load balancer pointed at a single DNS name, or be able to specify the private IP address that my container is going to get.  Anyone know a good solution for this?

I'm using a custom JSON template to deploy each time.  Is there a solution in that context, or the Azure CLI?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t assign a static private IP address to your Azure Container Instance

The private IP address might change when you restart the ACI or redeploy it

**Azure container instances don’t automatically register and synchronize the IP address with the associated DNS record**

**The private IP address allocation for a container instance is done based on the availability of the first available IP address in the subnet**

You can deploy the container group into a subnet of very small address range so that you can know the next private address which will be allocated to your container instance

Comment: OK.  Thank you.  This is what I was gathering, but didn't want to believe it was true.

Comment: How are your containers supposed to talk to each other if you can't reliably address them by name or IP?

Comment: The icing on the cake is, that containers get randomly redeployed with new IP without any interaction. The use for containers in Azure is pretty much limited due to this.